# Get the "real" Office version

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to downgrade my Office 365. To do so i need to get out the right Office version. But i have only the current version, which is `Version 1810 (Build 11001.20108)`. Its corresponding `real` version is `16.0.11001.20091`.

The version i want to downgrade is `Version 1809, Build 10827.20138` - but what is the corresponding "real" version (`16.0.xxxxx.yyyyy`), i can run the downgrade with a bat-file?

Answer (score 0):

got it: 16.0.10920.20003
Hint:

- firstly here get the date of update: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date
- Then here get the number corresponding to date: https://whatpulse.org/app/microsoft-office-click-to-run